# Input type number with max attribute and increment by manually typing value not returning correct value

Tags: html, jquery

I have 2 scripts.

Number 1 is a 2 buttons that when clicked, it increment / decrement the qty input number by certain amount (uses a data attribute for certain amount of increment / decrement) which is working fine. I also have a MAX attribute on the input number. The problem is, when you manually added the value on the button, it exceeds the max attribute

Example:

```
<input class="quantity-input quantity-element input" type="number" size="2" name="quantity" step="10" data-lot="10" value="10" min="10" max="53" autocomplete="off">
```

I uses the data attribute LOT for the increment/decrement (Step is not working for some reason)

So when manually changed the value (not clicking the buttons) it exceeds to 60.

Here's my code for the data-lot and quantity

```
updateQuantityManual: function updateQuantityManual(_this) {
    if (_this.is('[data-lot]')) {
      var lot = parseInt($(_this).attr('data-lot'), 10);
    }
    else {
      var lot = 1;
    }

    var qty = parseInt($(_this).val(), 10);
    
    if( qty % lot != 0 ) {
        var max = $(_this).attr('max');
        var myQty = parseInt(qty, 10);
        qty = myQty + lot - (qty % lot);
        
        $(_this).val(qty);
    }

  },
```

Please let me know why is that working like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by creating a new MAX VALUE which is MAX % data-lot and the value of that will then be reduced to the MAX VALUE.+

Answer (score 0):

Does following code your requirement?

```
<input class="quantity-input quantity-element input" type="number" size="2" maxlength="2"
       name="quantity" step="10" data-lot="10" value="10" min="10" max="53" 
       autocomplete="off" onChange="updateQuantityManual(this)">
```

and javascript

```
function updateQuantityManual(_this) {
 let lot = 1;
 let qty = parseInt($(_this).val(), 10);
 let max = parseInt($(_this).attr('max'));
 let myQty = parseInt(qty, 10);
 
 if (qty > max) {
     $(_this).val(max);
     return;
 }
 
 if ($(_this).data('lot')) {
   lot = parseInt($(_this).attr('data-lot'), 10);
 }


 if( qty % lot != 0) {
  qty = myQty + lot - (qty % lot);
  $(_this).val(qty);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately, one i click the increment button it actually goes straight to the MAX value. Like i mentioned above, the value should always follow the data-lot in this case, the max should be 50 since i have an increment of 10

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code solves your problem. Just replace your script with this:

```
$(".quantity-input").change(function () {
    var max = $(this).attr('max');
    if ($(this).val() > max) { // when manually increment
        $(this).val(max);
    } else {
        var lot = 1;
        if ($(this).is('[data-lot]')) {
            lot = parseInt($(this).attr('data-lot'), 10);
        }
        var qty = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (qty % lot != 0) {
            qty = qty + lot - (qty % lot);
            if(qty > max){
                $(this).val(max);
            }else{
                $(this).val(qty);
            }
        }
    }
});
```